# Can editable WPF ComboBox text be formatted differently to the formatting of the items in the drop-down?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have an editable ComboBox whose items are instances of a class:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Something { get; }
    public string Other { get; }
    public override string ToString() { return Something + "/" + Other; }
}
```

Thus the items are displayed like this: `1/Example`, `25/Etc` and so on.

When the user selects an item, I'd like the Text to be set to just the `Other` property, but the default behaviour is that the entire string is used as-displayed. For example, if the user selects `1/Example`, the editable text should be `Example`.

What's the best way to achieve the behaviour I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ComboBox TextSearch.TextPath="Other" IsEditable="True" Height="50" ItemsSource="{Binding FooItems}"/>
```

Comment: And so it does, though "Other" can't be a field, apparently. Incidentally, did you first discover it through searching online / reading about it, or perhaps by inspecting the ComboBox using some tool? (strongly suspect the former, but you never know...)

Answer (score 1):

Look into setting `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`.  This is the `DataTemplate` that the control will use to display items.  You can use this to obtain full control over how the `Foo` is displayed.

This will be a very useful skill in general because there are *many* tasks that you accomplish in WPF via modifications to data templates and control templates.

Comment: I'll check it out. Does it definitely not also affect how `Foo` gets converted to text when the user selects it?

Comment: It's a fundamental tool in the WPF toolset, so you definitely want to look into it.  You're basically creating a new visual tree to be used for displaying instances of a particular type (`Foo`, in this case).

Comment: When IsEditable is equal to false, the ComboBox uses a ContentPresenter to display the currently selected item; when IsEditable is equal to true, a TextBox is used for this purpose instead. Note that a TextBox only displays plain text, and that a ComboBoxItem may include non-plain text content, such as images.